# Where I can download JDK 7u411?

Tags: java, development-environment

Where I can download Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 411 (JDK 7u411)?

There is just release notes in official site. An older version, for example 401, will also work. A search on torrents turned out to be fruitless. Is there such a possibility at all?

Comment: Have you tried Google? I mean, I've found it after round about 3 seconds scrolling through the given link. I strongly encourage you to get comfortable with a search engine of your trust. It can help in many situations. Especially for software developers.

Comment: @cup Azul Systems offers 7u352b01. Oracle lists 7u411 but it is “restricted”.

Comment: Afaik, you need an Oracle account for many years to download development software from their servers. But the account is free, so one who desperately requires this outdated JDK version might sign up for one.

Comment: @Slevin Yes, i've tried Google. If you are so smart, give me a link to the distribution. And maybe I’ll buy a couple of mastery lessons from you.

Comment: @JohnyKage, here you go: https://www.google.com/search?q=JDK+7u411+download . It's the third link, at least for me, maybe you'll get some pr0n prior, so the link might be a little more down for you. However, in case even that's too complicated, here the direct link: https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase7-archive-downloads.html . Have fun and don't forget to vote.

Comment: @Slevin There is 7u80 for download, not 411. Thanks to people like the person who answered below. He has helped to understand the situation without unnecessary pathos.

Comment: @JohnyKage: So you're not even capable to scroll down the page to the `Java SE Development Kit 7u4` section? Well, the world seems really being lucky with raising AI, since otherwise we're all doomed...

Comment: @Slevin 7u4 is not 7u411.

Answer (score 7):

To quote the Oracle page, [*Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 411 (JDK 7u411) - Restricted*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/7-support-relnotes.html#R170_411) found on [this list](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/7-support-relnotes.html):

> As of July 2022, Java 7 has ended its service life. Oracle provides this restricted binary with and for the sole purpose of running some Oracle products. Please contact Oracle Support for more information.

So it would seem this version was never available publicly from Oracle. If you truly need that version of that Oracle product, contact Oracle Support for more info (as directed in that quote).

Oracle is but one of several JDK/JRE vendors. You can try checking with other vendors. These vendors include Azul Systems, Adoptium of the Eclipse Foundation, BellSoft, IBM, Red Hat, Amazon, Microsoft, SAP, and more.

I checked Azul Systems. The last one available for Java 7 at no charge [that I see](https://www.azul.com/downloads/#downloads-table-zulu) is 7u352b01. Azul Systems, like other JDK vendors, may have other offerings available to paying customers. So you may want to inquire.

---

Be aware that Java 7 was [end-of-life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_product) many years ago. See [this Oracle page](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2809708_1.html), and others. You *really* ought to be migrating to a modern [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version of Java (8, 11, 17, 21) or the current version (22).

- Migrating to Java 8 is likely to be easy.
- Migrating to 11 may be more problematic, especially regarding (a)
  [modularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) of your own code or that of dependency libraries,
  and (b) removing Java EE related parts (see [JEP 320](https://openjdk.org/jeps/320)).
- Moving on
  past 11 is likely smooth and easy. But of course you should study
  carefully the well-written *Release Notes* for each and every version
  to identify any issues that might impact your project.

Comment: A well-researched answer! The question is also clear; I'm unsure why someone has voted to close it.